# How can I store data in a CALayer?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-animation

I am creating a grid of CALayers, is there a way I can set a tag or something so that I can identify it if I need to?

I can probably just make a data model with an NSArray to keep track, but it would be easier for my implementation if I could just store it in the layer.

Comment: Why don't you just subclass `CALayer`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`CALayer` is a KVC compliant class, so you can set a value for any key.

For example:

```
[myLayer setValue: @"A TAG" forKey: @"someKey"];
```

You can then retrieve the value using:

```
value = [myLayer valueForKey: @"someKey"];
```

See the [Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/KVCAdditions.html) for more details.

Comment: Pedantic: it'd most correctly be "KVC compliant container class", surely? To be KVC compliant you just need your fixed list of defined properties to support key-value coding — I'm pretty sure it's the container bit that says you can make up your own properties.

Comment: Excellent thanks, I have heard of KVC before, but never thought about it because I didn't have a reason to.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using a layout manager that cares about it, the `name` property (an `NSString*`) should serve.